# Is there any way to monitor the compiled code cache in Java?

Tags: java

OK - I know I can run my java process like this :

```
java -XX:+PrintCompilation <FooProgram>
```

and I can see output like:

```
c:\>java -XX:+PrintCompilation -jar c:\FooProgram.jar
  1       java.lang.String::charAt (33 bytes)
  2       java.lang.Math::max (11 bytes)
  1%      java.util.jar.JarFile::hasClassPathAttribute @ 78 (197 bytes)
  3       java.lang.String::hashCode (60 bytes)
  4       java.lang.String::indexOf (151 bytes)
  5       java.util.Properties$LineReader::readLine (452 bytes)
  6       java.lang.Object::<init> (1 bytes)
  7       java.lang.String::indexOf (166 bytes)
  8       java.lang.String::equals (88 bytes)
```

to give me an idea of what methods are compiled, uncompiled, marked as zombies, etc.  Is there anyway to monitor the usage of the code cache where these methods get compiled into?  I see a message when the compiler code cache is full saying something like: "I'm full, no more compilations for you...", but it would seem as though something like this is a lagging indicator that we have a problem.  I know how to print the max size of the code cache, what I'm looking for really is a way to see how its being filled up over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JConsole will tell you. You can also install Java-monitor in your app server and look at the code cache in the "see all measurements" page for a host. http://java-monitor.com

Comment: Hi Kees, you're right it does.  I discovered that this morning -- it would be nice if there were a -XX flag that printed out the code cache and gosh maybe even *what* exactly was in it.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Indeed, that would be nice. Have you tried to make a heap dump and analyse that with a memory profiler?

Alternately, check where in the code you generate dynamic classes (proxies, for example) and see if that code is sane.

Comment: Where in JConsole does it give you this information?  I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @mattforsythe JConsole shows "Code Cache" on the Memory tab when you switch the chart choice.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but... I'll answer anyways...
I have build a VisualVM plugin that will monitor stats about the code cache. It has been included in the open source version plug-in repository. Alternatively you can down load it and the source from java.net.

Oops, forgot link... https://java.net/projects/memorypoolview/

Comment: It would help people reading this if you mentioned the name of said plugin, and/or a link to it.

Answer (score 2):

Since Java 8 you can use `-XX:+PrintCodeCache` more details [can be found in this paper](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/embedded/develop-apps-platforms/codecache.htm)

Comment: `–XX:+PrintCodeCache` gives only single output on application exit. According to attached paper there is also `–XX:+PrintCodeCacheOnCompilation` option that also produces the same output as produced by `–XX:+PrintCodeCache`, but does so each time a method is compiled. It might be more suitable for the author of the question.

Comment: And remember to use hyphen-minus (U+002D) (not en-dash (U+2013)) before JVM options `–Xmx1G # incorrect: en dash`   `-Xmx1g # correct: hyphen-minus` because I used incorrect en-dash (U+2013) in previous comment :)