# what compiled code is stored in the JVM CodeCache area

Tags: java, jvm, jit

One server's CPU usage gradually gone to 100%, and I found the CodeCache area occupied 231M while the threshold is 240M.

Other server in my cluster is fine,CPU usage is 30% and CodeCache area occupied 110M.

I want to know what compiled code is stored in the CodeCache area while the server can't be restart to avoid destroying the scene .

Does it exist code cache dump?

ps:jdk version is 1.8

Answer (score 2):

With more recent JDK versions you can use `jcmd Compiler.codecache` and **`jcmd Comiler.codelist`**.
With 1.8, try -XX:+PrintCodeCache or –XX:+PrintCodeCacheOnCompilation although this will give you only summary statistics (see [Is there any way to monitor the compiled code cache in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368068/is-there-any-way-to-monitor-the-compiled-code-cache-in-java)).

The jcmd `codelist` command is handled by the JVM's [`CodeCache::print_codelist`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11u/blob/5f01925b80ed851b133ee26fbcb07026ac04149e/src/hotspot/share/code/codeCache.cpp#L1651) method but this is not available in JDK 8 - all that's there is [`print_summary`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/master/hotspot/src/share/vm/code/codeCache.cpp#L972).

PS: I've also tried to generate a core dump with `gcore` but failed to see how to analyze the Code Cache this way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple program you can use to dump CodeCache on JDK 8.

```
import sun.jvm.hotspot.code.CodeBlob;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.code.CodeCacheVisitor;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.Address;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VM;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool;

public class DumpCodeCache extends Tool {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        VM.getVM().getCodeCache().iterate(new CodeCacheVisitor() {

            public void prologue(Address start, Address end) {
            }

            public void visit(CodeBlob blob) {
                System.out.printf("%8d  %s\n", blob.getSize(), blob.getName());
            }

            public void epilogue() {
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DumpCodeCache().execute(args);
    }
}
```

The tool is based on [Serviceabiliy Agent](http://www.javamagazine.mozaicreader.com/JanFeb2017/Default/29/0) technology.
To compile and run it, include `$JAVA_HOME/lib/sa-jdi.jar` in the classpath.

```
java -cp $JAVA_HOME/lib/sa-jdi.jar:. DumpCodeCache PID
```

Since JDK 9 there is a builtin feature to dump the CodeCache with jcmd:

```
jcmd PID Compiler.codelist
```

Since JDK 11 there is even more powerful command to print the detailed CodeCache stats:

```
jcmd PID Compiler.CodeHeap_Analytics
```

Comment: thanks a lot.
I find There are 20,000 Nmethods with the same name, and the name is `NMethod for org/apache/coyote/AbstractProcessor.parseHost(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/buf/MessageBytes;)V`. 
most of them are zombie or non entrant ? how to identify the difference? and which case can cause this problem?